# Which package should I install to get Python IDLE on CrOS

Tags: linux, debian, installation, python

I have a requirement for using the native Python IDLE IDE when completing work for a course I'm in.  This wasn't much of a problem on my desktop computer, but on my notebook (which is running CrOS), IDLE doesn't appear to be bundled with the native Python package (or if it is, there's no obvious method to call IDLE after installing).

On WinOS platforms, IDLE comes bundled with the Python binary install, so once Python3.11 is installed IDLE appears as a start menu entry, or can be directly invoked through run dialog prompt or cmd.exe, etc.  However, this doesn't seem to be the case for CrOS/Linux/WSL platforms, so I just wanted to verify exactly which package is the correct one to install and use for class?

On Debian Bullseye, `apt search IDLE` results in multiple hits, including:

```
...
idle/stable 3.9.2-3 all   IDE for Python using Tkinter (default version)

idle-python2.7/stable 2.7.18-8 all   IDE for Python (v2.7) using Tkinter

idle-python3.9/stable 3.9.2-1 all   IDE for Python (v3.9) using Tkinter

idle3/stable 3.9.2-3 all   IDE for Python using Tkinter (transitional package)
...
```

I'm guessing `idle/stable 3.9.2-3 all` would most likely be
the correct package, but just wanted to confirm for certain.

Comment: One thing you may try is [pip](https://pypi.org/project/idle/).

Comment: Hi @TomYan, I need to take another look once I get back, but it was giving me some issue due to the system python not matching the installed python3, or something to that effect?  It popped up with that error when I tried to use an argument to ensure it runs default pip/IDLE.  I read I should install a VM, dispite CrOS already running on one, and there's not enough resources available to run a seperate one altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct choice was actually `idle-python3.9/stable 3.9.2-1 all` for my use case.